# Do I need a dummy load for a GPS satellite signal generator?

Tags: gps, gnss

*I'm in the process of applying for an FCC experimental certificate so I can be legal when I purchase a satellite generator.*

I found a used (calibrated) generator on eBay and want to know if I need a dummy load on the RF outputs that aren't being used. The is one on the front limited to -110 dBm and the one on the back is labeled CAL/MON and is always on and transmitted at -48 dBm.

I understand those signal levels are VERY LOW. **Do I still need a dummy load on the unused port?**

Comment: do you mean dBm ? Please add datasheet, etc. describing the generator, I would say in generic, to terminate every unused output.

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: With that low power, pretty much all 50 ohm terminators should be good enough as a dummy load.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Datasheet shows nothing about terminating unused outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with the manufacturer, a dummy load is not typically used on signals lower than -70dBm as a rule of thumb. To paraphrase the response I received, the VSWR due to an open load at such small signal levels does not negatively affect transmission line characteristics internal to the generator.

Comment: No. you ABSOLUTELY MUST use a dummy load.  I will add an answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

## **YOU ABSOLUTELY MUST USE A DUMMY LOAD. NOT DOING SO HAS SERIOUS CONSEQUENCES**

There is a famous GPS disruption event known as the [Portland Spoofing Incident](https://www.gps.gov/governance/advisory/meetings/2017-11/scott2.pdf), ironically at the world's largest GPS conference.

It was caused by a professional signal simulator - broadcasting actual GPS power levels of roughly -130dBm - not being fitted with a dummy load.

Whilst it did not penetrate outside the building, it had several consequences:

- Some phones set their date to 2014, which was the date of the GPS simulation.
- Some phones were unable to perform normal function like fetching email because of the bad timestamp information.
- Some phones were unable to recover without a factory fresh firmware reinstall.

So please use a [dummy load](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Mini-Circuits/ANNE-50L%2b?qs=xZ%2FP%252Ba9zWqZeNkqGFDtO3Q%3D%3D).